# How two different URLs can be forwarded to a single URL with single JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am using blogspot. I want to learn how two/ or three different URLs can be forwarded to a single URL with single JavaScript?
Example;

https://www.example.com/2021/05/test-post.html
https://www.example.com/2021/05/test-post.html?m=1

Should be redirected to

https://www.website.com/2021/12/official-post.html

I have a JavaScript that is able to redirect it but it works only for Single URL. I can insert the same JavaScript twice with to different URLs one by one pointing to the same target URL but it is bit time consuming and increasing the JavaScript in the theme that can affect the website speed.

**Here is the Javascript code**

```
<script>
if(window.location.href == 'https://www.example.com/2021/05/test-post.html')
{
window.location="https://www.website.com/2021/12/official-post.html";
}
</script>

<script>
if(window.location.href == 'https://www.example.com/2021/05/test-post.html?m=1')
{
window.location="https://www.website.com/2021/12/official-post.html";
}
</script>
```

I want something like this

```
<script>
if(window.location.href == 'https://www.example.com/2021/05/test-post.html')
if(window.location.href == 'https://www.example.com/2021/05/test-post.html?m=1'
{
window.location="https://www.website.com/2021/12/official-post.html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't tag Java in JavaScript question. That's a completely different language.

Comment: Try using OR `||` operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Comment: @TheWhiteFang, Thanks bro It works. <3 Let me know how can I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: You can't make a comment answer. And my comment does not qualify as an answer. So it's alright ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Logical OR (||) works here***

**Do this**

```
<script>
if(window.location.href == 'https://www.example.com/2021/05/test-post.html' || 'https://www.example.com/2021/05/test-post.html?m=1')

{
window.location="https://www.website.com/2021/12/official-post.html";
}
</script>
```